# How to change the Unity Launcher's icon theme?

Tags: 10.10, unity, ubuntu-netbook, icons, appearance

Does anyone know how to change Unity icon-theme? For instance I use Faenza in my desktop session, but unity does not use it, both in panel and panel apps (applications and documents). So, anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you merge the icon theme you want with humanity and humanity-dark icon themes in /usr/share/icons you can change the theme. I'm using Faenza icons with Unity right now and it looks nice. Just remember to backup the Humanity folder first and rename it.

Comment: So that, we can simply rename the index.theme's "Name=",am I wrong? I think it would be easier.

Answer (score 3):

That's a 100$ question dude. Apparently Unity is just stuck on Humanity icons set. I just don't know why. Maybe you should follow this launchpad entry:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/663524

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, right now you can't.

Comment: I hope in 11.04 it will be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Faenza was missing icons, so I just merged it with Humanity. After backing up of course. The index.theme wouldn't add those icons for me.

Answer (score -3):

In the application menu, choose Appearance. 
At the bottom of the "Theme" tab, select Edit, then change your icons in the "Icons" tab.

However I don't know if this will change the icons on the left dock.

Comment: I know how to change the icon theme. But it does not affect Unity Interface (Dock, Applicationsa and Documents Menu, Indicators)